# Error al importar `pydot` pero ya instalé` pydot`

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, graphviz, pydot

En un jupyter notebook en un entorno virtual

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

Pero me dice

```
ImportError: Failed to import `pydot`. Please install `pydot`. For example with `pip install pydot`.
```

Sin embargo cuando hicé con el entorno virtual :

```
>>> pip list :
...
pydot               1.2.4
```

Intenté con `pip` y `pip3` :

```
(mybotenv) mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/mybot$ pip3 install pydot
Requirement already satisfied: pydot in ./mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.1.4 in ./mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pydot) (2.2.0)
```

Y mi version de Python es:

```
(mybotenv) mike@mike-Inspiron-3543:~/Documents/programming/mybot$ python -V
Python 3.5.2
```

#### Actualizacion

Apagué y reinicialicé el jupyter kernel y ahora obtengo:

```
`pydot` failed to call GraphViz.Please install GraphViz (https://www.graphviz.org/) and ensure that its executables are in the $PATH.
```

Comment: estas trabajando con virtualenv?? , ejecuta el comando pip freeze, en todo caso la respuesta que te dieron es buena solo falta que antes de hacer eso hagas un pip uninstall pydot

Comment: @JackNavaRow Gracias por el comentario, `pip freeze` me da `pydot==1.2.4` antes y después el `pip uninstall pydot && pip3 install pydot`

Comment: borralo con `pip uninstall pydot`, y luego ejecutas `pyp3 install pydot`

Comment: Y ya instalaste graphviz? dot es un ejecutable parte de graphviz

Answer (score 0):

Visto que comentas con el tag `python-3.x` entiendo que el problema es que estás utilizando el comando `pip`válido para Python 2.

Si quieres instalar un módulo para Python 3 tienes que utilizar `pip3` o `easy_install`, por lo que la instalación quedaría así:

```
pip3 install pydot
```

Comment: no, lo siento. Ya lo hicé